# Arm thumb2 mov value into register instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, mov, thumb

When using `MOVS.W  R8, #0` (5FF00008)   in arm thumb2 (32 bits)

is R8 now equal to 4 bytes of 0 ? or only the left/right byte equal to zero?

Comment: The `.w` just indicates that the instruction is encoded in 32 bits instead of 16 bits.  While there is no 16 bit encoding for this instruction due to the use of Hi register `R8`, an encoding does exist if the register is a Lo register like `R0`.  For example, `movs r0, #0` is `2000` hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate is zero-extended(*) to 32 bits, so you end up with `0x00000000` in your example.

See page 4-166 in *ARM Architecture Reference Manual **Thumb-2 Supplement*** (ARM DDI 0308D)

---

* In the case of a 12-bit immediate it might not be a simple zero-extension, but it's still extended to 32 bits in some fashion.